# How to decode and update input data of a specific transaction?

Tags: transactions, ethers.js, blocks, hash, meta-data

[image]

So, I've decoded the input-data and fetched it via block-hash, Now what I want to do is that, I want to update the input data and post that updated input data back to the same transaction of the same block, Is this possible ? If yes then how ?

Answer (score 2):

no it's not possible. a transaction is an immutable record of something that has happened. It doesn't make sense to be able to change it as it would mean there could be no certainty on the blockchain.
If a transaction was changed, doing so would invalidate the block it's in and all subsequent blocks.

Comment: There is small exception when a chain restructuring takes places and the mined transaction is removed from the new block. But that can not be relied upon.